# String.equals() always returns false?

Tags: android, web-services

I am trying to make a sign in page for an android app. My team leader has decided to make this with a webservice.

Whenever a uses logs in, a request is sent, with 3 possible responses:

```
0: Wrong Password
20: Wrong username
otherwise: a UUID
```

I am trying to validate the results given back by the webservice like this:

```
    String resultString = result.toString();
    if (resultString.equals("20")) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Het ingevulde emailadres klopt niet!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    } else if (resultString.equals("0")) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Het ingevulde wachtwoord klopt niet!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Debug, klopt", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
   }
```

Seems like basic code to me. However, this code always shows the bottom statement, so it lets the first 2 pass as false.

For debugging purposes, am also returning the `resultString` to my console. (removed that line in the sample). There I can very obviously see that the result given back is in fact `20`.

How can it be that such simple code does not do what I want it to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Check if there is no space

Comment: check the length of the resultString.

Comment: As response is not exactly what you are comparing ("0" and "20") instead of `equals` you should use `contains`

Comment: You could even check on length of received string. Not neat, but it seems a UUID is always longer then length 2 of "20"

Comment: `byte[] b = resultString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));` write `b` here

Comment: @SilentKiller A hero among men! Would you make that into an answer so I can accept?

Comment: @WesleyPeeters thanks man.. :) done with answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response is not exactly the string you are comparing which are "0" and "20". but the response is

```
0: Wrong Password
20: Wrong username
otherwise: a UUID
```

if you want to compare the string then it should be

**Options : 1**

```
String resultString = result.toString();
if (resultString.equals("20: Wrong username")) {
    // code
} else if (resultString.equals("0: Wrong Password")) {
    // code
} else {
    // code
}
```

**Option : 2**

Instead of `eqauls` you should use `contains`

```
String resultString = result.toString();
if (resultString.contains("20")) {
    // code
} else if (resultString.contains("0")) {
    // code
} else {
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The code seems to be ok... Maybe a white space in the result? 
Try trimming the `resultString`.
which es 20, `result` or `resultString`?

As an advice, it is usually better do `"".equals(object)` because otherwise, if the object is null it will throw `NullpointerExceptcion`

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all of the above - the code does look good.

Try using `String.compareTo` and look at the `int` returned value to check for hidden differences.

Also, try printing `String.toCharArray` + `String.length` to identify extra characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking the complete string returned from web service without extracting the code (0 or 20) then you need to replace 'equals' with 'contains'.